# What's the best way to maintain application properties files?

Tags: deployment, properties, soa

I am starting on a project where we provide an application container, deployment tools and services to application teams in our enterprise.

Most of those teams deploy their applications in a large number of combinations of regions and environments.

Frequently the application properties vary from region to region and env to env.

We currently have a rube goldberg kind of process where we distribute a hierarchical set of properties, which are dynamically consumed into the application on startup. Some examples of properties might be JDBC strings, regional UI screen entitlements; etc, very application specific kinds of things.

In our nextgen incarnation we would like to streamline the properties management. It seems like a pretty common problem and I am wondering if there are existing open source or otherwise solutions?

Comment: +1 for the Rube Goldberg comparison to many general approaches to build/release. I feel your pain.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that build and release processes in most companies are woefully out of date with how development has changed.

It used to be the case that developers were responsible for writing programs, and then they would hand their code off to admins who would understand how and where the code would run, what remoting technologies would be used, etc.

That model is so outdated it's not uncommon for it to be the case that the devs are the only people in the whole company who understand all the hows and wheres (and whys) of their code in the wild.

However, they are the least empowered to do something with that knowledge, so are in the impossible position of having to satisfy an outdated set of build/deployment standards just to get code out into production.

I have seen and played with a few code-first deployment tools, most recently [con-dep](http://www.con-dep.net/), all with the lofty and noble goal of liberating developers from the build and release merry-go-round.